# How to get values from an array, inside another array, with stdClass Objects?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I'm trying to get the values from `[iso_3166_1]` and `[title]` in an array, which is inside another array.

I have searched and tried several solutions and tips, but none of them works, and now I'm stuck.

**The content is fetched like this**

```
$content = json_decode($jsonFile);
```

**Then I have the following content**

```
stdClass Object (
    [id] => 508947 [titles] => Array (
         [0] => stdClass Object ( [iso_3166_1] => FR [title] => Devenir rouge [type] => )
         [1] => stdClass Object ( [iso_3166_1] => MX [title] => Red [type] => )
         [2] => stdClass Object ( [iso_3166_1] => LV [title] => Es sarkstu [type] => )
         [3] => stdClass Object ( [iso_3166_1] => NO [title] => Rød [type] => )
         [4] => stdClass Object ( [iso_3166_1] => SE [title] => Röd [type] => )
         [5] => stdClass Object ( [iso_3166_1] => PE [title] => Red [type] => )
    )
)
```

I have tried to make a `foreach` loop like this for instance, but that only gives me `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`:

```
foreach($content as $row) {
    foreach($row['titles'] as $country) {
        echo $country['iso_3166_1']['title'];
   }
}
```

I have also tried tho following, to try get rid of the stdClass Objects in the array, which does not seem to work either:

```
$content = json_decode(json_encode($content), true);
$content = (array)$content;
```

Comment: You've misread your output. `$content` is not an array, but already an object. You have one loop in excess `foreach($content['titles'] as $country) { ... }`

Comment: btw, `$content = json_decode($jsonFile); $content = json_decode(json_encode($content), true);` is overkill, just do `$content = json_decode($jsonFile, true);`, this is enough

Comment: try `foreach ($content->titles as $country) { echo $country->iso_3166_1, $country->title; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you to compare & understand why your code fails.

```
$titles = $content->titles;

foreach ($titles as $country_instance) {
    echo $country_instance->iso_3166_1;
    echo '-';
    echo $country_instance->title;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right, `json_decode` associative mode should return arrays of arrays from your JSON.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

You can also try using flag `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY` but from what I've read it only does something when `null` is supplied as the second argument.